# WSO2 - Policy Management (XACML) using API

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

I am studying about XACML and testing polices using WSO2 IS.

I can handle the XACML policies (create, disable, change, etc.) using WSO2 IS API?

Where can I find examples, documentation, etc.?

I found this example [1] in Java (usage WSO2 libs/jars), but my tests are in Python.

[1] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pap/5.X.X/src/main/java/org/xacmlinfo/xacml/pap/is/PolicyAdminClient.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle XACML policies in WSO2 Identity Server through the SOAP API using Python or another programming language.

The WSDL for the API can be retrieved from the URL: `https://{ip-address}:{port}/services/EntitlementPolicyAdminService?wsdl`

If you are not familiar with WSDL using Python, try to play a little with SOAPUI or Postman. That typically helps to get started with the SOAP API